# How to retrieve another variable within table in Lua?

Tags: function, variables, lua, return, lua-table

how can I use `title` in `shortdesc`?

This fails:

```
function descriptor()
    return {
        title = "This";
        shortdesc = title .. " is my text."
    }
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't; you can use a local variable though:

```
function descriptor()
    local title = "This"
    return {
        title = title;
        shortdesc = title .. " is my text."
    }
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Paul is correct. You can also construct the table in pieces:

```
function descriptor()
    local t = {}
    t.title = "This";
    t.shortdesc = t.title .. " is my text."
    return t
end
```